# pandas: how to group by time intervals of varying length?

Tags: pandas, time, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I know that it is possible to group your data by time intervals of the same length by using the function `resample`. But how can I group by time intervals of custom length (i.e. irregular time intervals)?

Here is an example:
Say we have a dataframe with time values, like this:

```
rng = pd.date_range(start='2015-02-11', periods=7, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })
```

And we have the following time intervals:

2015-02-12 -----
2015-05-10

2015-05-10 -----
2015-08-20

2015-08-20 -----
2016-01-01

It is clear that rows with index 0,1,2 belong to the first time interval, rows with index 3,4,5 belong to the second time interval and row 7 belongs to the last time interval.

My question is: how do I group these rows according to those specific time intervals, in order to perform aggregate functions (e.g. mean) on them?

Comment: Show us a example of dataframe and how do you want the output.

Comment: I imagine something with `pd.cut` to have the time bin, then group on that.'